# firefox updates

Tags: updates, firefox

I bought a laptop with preinstalled ubuntu 18.04.4; the firefox version also preinstalled is 72.01 but when running updates these are not allowed.
Can anyone suggest whether I should uninstall it and then install the most recent firefox version or not bother since it seems to be working ok apart from being slower than chrome?
thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate "these are not allowed"?

Comment: What is the output of `apt list|grep -i firefox/`.

Comment: Hi FedonKadifeli thanks for your reply this is the output firefox/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 73.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [residual-config]

Comment: Sorry for the delay Pilot6 I should have mentioned that when running sudo apt install firefox, version 73 is installed but 72 remains (not sure where) and never gets updated. So for now I have kept the original version. Hope clearer now?? Thanks for your time

Comment: Why do you feel "72" remains? What do you mean by "I kept the original version"? How did you do that? Please [edit] your question to provide the entire output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` and `apt policy firefox`.

Comment: Also, there should be no reason to run `sudo apt install firefox`. Firefox is part of a normal Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @ DK Bose that command was suggested on firefox site; if I run it, firefox 73 is installed but I end up with 2 firefox shortcuts ine directing to 72 and the other to 73..... Thanks for your reply

Comment: apt policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 73.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
     73.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     59.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages